# What's the distribution of $(n_1+n_2+n_3)/\sqrt{N_1N_2N_3}$ with $n_i$ running from $0$ to $N_i - 1$

Tags: sequences-and-series, probability-distributions, normal-distribution

I am wondering what's the distribution of $$\frac{n_1+n_2+n_3}{\sqrt{N_1N_2N_3}} \text{ with } n_i=0,\ldots,N_{i}-1$$ A quick check using matlab gives that the histogram of this sequence follows a Gaussian distribution. I am wondering how I can prove this analytically.

Thanks for your response in advance!

Comment: Are you considering continuous or discrete distributions? It should not make much of a difference on large scale, but it might be the case to improve the context of this question. The PDF of the sum of three independent, uniformly distributed random variables is piecewise-parabolic (and pretty much Gaussian-shaped) by switching to the characteristic functions and exploiting Fourier inversion. The integrals $$\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty}\left(\frac{\sin x}{x}\right)^n\,dx $$ are involved in the proof of the central limit theorem for the binomial distribution.

Comment: I am referring to a discrete distribution with $n_i$ and $N_i$ integers. Let's say if  $N_1=N_2=N_3=100$ then the histogram of the above expression follows a Gaussian distribution.

Comment: The "*level of Gaussianity*" for a fixed $n$ is quantified by the [Berry-Esseen theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Berry%E2%80%93Esseen_theorem).

Comment: For fixed $N_1,N_2,N_3$ the distribution is just a scaled version of the distribution of $n_1+n_2+n_3.$

Comment: Thank you both for your replies. Now the main question I am having is that: How I can prove what the distribution of $\frac{\sqrt{2 \pi}}{\sqrt{n_1 +n_2+n_3}} \bigg[ C \bigg(\sqrt{(n_1 +n_2+n_3)\mu)} \sqrt{\frac{2}{\pi}}\bigg) - S \bigg(\sqrt{(n_1 +n_2+n_3)\mu)} \sqrt{\frac{2}{\pi}}\bigg) \bigg]$, where C and S denote the cos and sine Fresnel integrals and $\mu = 1/\sqrt{N_1N_2N_3}$.

Comment: @MariosZacharias: How can you prove that the distribution of (insert monstrosity) does what?

Answer (score 0):

If $A,B,C$ are independent random variables, uniformly distributed over $(0,a),(0,b),(0,c)$, the [characteristic function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Characteristic_function_(probability_theory)) of $A+B+C$ is given by
$$ \frac{i(1-e^{iat})}{at}\cdot \frac{i(1-e^{ibt})}{bt}\cdot \frac{i(1-e^{ict})}{ct} $$
and the PDF of $A+B+C$ can be recovered by (Fourier) [inversion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Characteristic_function_(probability_theory)#Inversion_formulae), i.e. by computing
$$ \frac{1}{2\pi}\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty}\frac{i(1-e^{iat})}{at}\cdot \frac{i(1-e^{ibt})}{bt}\cdot \frac{i(1-e^{ict})}{ct} e^{-itx}\,dt, $$
usually through the residue theorem. We may also notice that the PDF of $A+B$ is the convolution of the PDFs of $A$ and $B$, hence it is a continuous and piecewise-linear function. Similarly, the PDF of $A+B+C$ is a $C^1$, piecewise-quadratic function.

If $A,B,C\sim U\left(-1,1\right)$ the PDF of $A+B+C$ is explicitly given by $$\frac{(3-x)|3-x|-3(1-x)|1-x|-3(1+x)|1+x|+(3+x)|3+x|}{32}$$
and the following diagram provides a comparison between the PDF of $A+B+C$ (blue) and the PDF of the standard normal distribution (purple). Indeed they are pretty close, as the [Berry-Esseen theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Berry%E2%80%93Esseen_theorem) ensures.

[image]

Actually a better Gaussian approximation of the PDF of $A+B+C$ is $\sqrt{\frac{7}{16\pi}}\exp\left(-\frac{7x^2}{16}\right)$.

We may deal with discrete distributions along the same lines, I just picked continuous distributions since the Fourier inversion theorem has a more compact form.

Comment: Thank you for your reply  ! I tried to reproduce your result for the PDF but I am missing a factor of 2 ! I get 1/16 instead of 1/32 in the denominator. Is there a strategy to find the Gaussian approximation or your answer is intuitive ?

Comment: @mz_physics: one may find the optimal Gaussian approximation by solving a least-square problem, the second approximation I provided above is just a consequence of a lucky guess, and it can be probably further improved into an optimal $L^2$-fit.